# How to get index of a TStatusPanel (StatusBar - Delphi)?

Tags: delphi, statusbar

I'm trying to get the index of a `TStatusPanel` (Panel of a `TStatusBar`) in the `OnDblClick` event to use it with `ShowMessage()`, for example, but I don't know how to get the index.

I know that events like `OnDrawPanel` have a `Panel: TStatusPanel` parameter, but I need the same thing in `OnDblClick` but there is only one parameter, `Sender: TObject`.

There are no commands like `if StatusBar.Panel = 1`, for example. I can use `StatusBar.Panels[0]` but I have no idea how to compare the index clicked to show my message.

Well, that's what I need on a easy way:

```
if StatusBar.Panel = 0 then
  showmessage('0')
else if StatusBar.Panel = 1 then
  showmessage('1');
```

I know the code above does not work, it's just an example. It should be something like this:

```
if StatusBar.Panels[0].'SOMETHING' = 0 then
  showmessage('0')
else if StatusBar.Panels[0].'SOMETHING' = 1 then
  showmessage('1');
```

Comment: Call GetMessagePos and work out which panel was clicked

Comment: David Heffernan, thanks for the answer, but the StatusBar is on a resizable form, GetMessagePos returns different positions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `GetMessagePos` in `OnDblClick` event handler to get the mouse position when the `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message is retrieved that fires the double click handler and convert to client coordinates. Then you can iterate over the panels of the status bar to locate which part the mouse was on. Example:

```
procedure TForm1.StatusBar1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
  i, w: Integer;
begin
  Pt := SmallPointToPoint(TSmallPoint(DWORD(GetMessagePos)));
  MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, StatusBar1.Handle, Pt, 1);
  w := 0;
  for i := 0 to StatusBar1.Panels.Count - 1 do begin
    w := w + StatusBar1.Panels[i].Width;
    if Pt.X < w then begin
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(i));
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Optionally you can instead use the `OnMouseDown` event handler, which client coordinates where the mouse is clicked are already passed, and test for a double click in the event handler and then locate the panel. There's no side effect to using the `OnMouseDown` handler as it is fired from the same `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` when there is a double click.

```
procedure TForm1.StatusBar1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  i, w: Integer;
begin
  if (Button = mbLeft) and (ssDouble in Shift) then begin
    w := 0;
    for i := 0 to StatusBar1.Panels.Count - 1 do begin
      w := w + StatusBar1.Panels[i].Width;
      if X < w then begin
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(i));
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Used and works perfectly in my "Glitch" Desktop Terminal... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [`SB_GETPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760746.aspx) instead of [`SB_GETRECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760748.aspx).  That way, you are sending fewer messages to the `TStatusBar`:

```
uses
  ..., Winapi.CommCtrl;

function GetStatusPanelAt(StatusBar: TStatusBar; X, Y: Integer): TStatusPanel; overload;
function GetStatusPanelAt(StatusBar: TStatusBar; const P: TPoint): TStatusPanel; overload;

...

function GetStatusPanelAt(StatusBar: TStatusBar; X, Y: Integer): TStatusPanel;
begin
  Result := GetStatusPanelAt(StatusBar, Point(X, Y));
end;

function GetStatusPanelAt(StatusBar: TStatusBar; const P: TPoint): TStatusPanel;
var
  index: Integer;
  arr: array of Integer;
  Panel: TStatusPanel;
begin
  Result := nil;

  if not PtInRect(StatusBar.ClientRect, P) then
    Exit;

  SetLength(arr, SendMessage(StatusBar.Handle, SB_GETPARTS, 0, 0));
  SendMessage(StatusBar.Handle, SB_GETPARTS, Length(arr), LPARAM(PInteger(arr)));

  index := 0;
  while index < Length(arr) do
  begin
    if (P.X <= arr[index]) or (arr[index] = -1) then
    begin
      Result := StatusBar.Panels[index];
      Exit;
    end;
    Inc(index);
  end;
end;
```

Then you can do this:

```
uses
  ..., System.Types, Winapi.Windows;

procedure TForm5.StatusBar1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
  Panel: TStatusPanel;
begin
  Pt := SmallPointToPoint(TSmallPoint(GetMessagePos()));
  Pt := StatusBar1.ScreenToClient(Pt);

  Panel := GetStatusPanelAt(StatusBar1, Pt);
  if Panel <> nil then
    ShowMessage('Click on Panel ' + IntToStr(Panel.Index))
  else
    ShowMessage('No click on a Panel');
end;
```

Alternativly, if you are using D2006 or later, you can wrap the logic into a class helper instead:

```
uses
  ..., Winapi.CommCtrl;

type
  TStatusBarHelper = class helper for TStatusBar
  public
    function GetPanelAt(X, Y: Integer): TStatusPanel; overload;
    function GetPanelAt(const P: TPoint): TStatusPanel; overload;
  end;

...

function TStatusBarHelper.GetPanelAt(X, Y: Integer): TStatusPanel;
begin
  Result := GetPanelAt(Point(X, Y));
end;

function TStatusBarHelper.GetPanelAt(const P: TPoint): TStatusPanel;
var
  index: Integer;
  arr: array of Integer;
  Panel: TStatusPanel;
begin
  Result := nil;

  if not PtInRect(Self.ClientRect, P) then
    Exit;

  SetLength(arr, SendMessage(Self.Handle, SB_GETPARTS, 0, 0));
  SendMessage(Self.Handle, SB_GETPARTS, Length(arr), LPARAM(PInteger(arr)));

  index := 0;
  while index < Length(arr) do
  begin
    if (P.X <= arr[index]) or (arr[index] = -1) then
    begin
      Result := Self.Panels[index];
      Exit;
    end;
    Inc(index);
  end;
end;
```

```
uses
  ..., System.Types, Winapi.Windows;

procedure TForm5.StatusBar1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
  Panel: TStatusPanel;
begin
  Pt := SmallPointToPoint(TSmallPoint(GetMessagePos()));
  Pt := StatusBar1.ScreenToClient(Pt);

  Panel := StatusBar1.GetPanelAt(Pt);
  if Panel <> nil then
    ShowMessage('Click on Panel ' + IntToStr(Panel.Index))
  else
    ShowMessage('No click on a Panel');
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost the same logic but it gets actual panel bounds from the StatusBar. In other words it will return -1 if you click on a separator between panels.

```
uses 
  Winapi.CommCtrl;

procedure TForm1.StatusBar1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LClickPos: TPoint;
  LIndex: Integer;

  function GetPanelIndex: Integer;
  var
    I: Integer;
    LRect: TRect;
  begin
    for I := 0 to StatusBar1.Panels.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if SendMessage(StatusBar1.Handle, SB_GETRECT, I, LPARAM(@LRect)) <> 0 then
      begin
        if PtInRect(LRect, LClickPos) then
          Exit(I);
      end;
    end;

    Result := -1;
  end;

begin
  LClickPos := SmallPointToPoint(TSmallPoint(GetMessagePos()));
  LClickPos := StatusBar1.ScreenToClient(LClickPos);
  LIndex := GetPanelIndex;

  Application.MessageBox(PChar(Format('Panel %d', [LIndex])), 'Test');
end;
```

Comment: You've been more accurate with SB_RECT but then gave up on accuracy with GetCursorPos.

Comment: It is really important to use GetMessagePos

Comment: Thanks, fixed to GetMessagePos

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution and it worked for me. Simple and plain!

First, write a handler for the OnMouseDown event of the StatusBar

```
procedure TfrmMain.StatusBarMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
  TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  TComponent(Sender).Tag := X;
end;
```

Then write a handler for the OnDoublClick event of the StatusBar

```
procedure TfrmMain.StatusBarDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  AccumelatedWidth, i : Integer;
begin
  AccumelatedWidth := 0;
  for i := 0 to StatusBar.Panels.Count - 1 do
    begin
      AccumelatedWidth := AccumelatedWidth + StatusBar.Panels[i].Width;
      if StatusBar.Tag < AccumelatedWidth then
        begin
          ShowMessage ('You clicked panel ' + i.ToString);
          Break;
        end;
    end;
end;
```